# how to copy one column from one spreadsheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy the data from column A in spreadsheet called "Dividends" and paste in spreadsheet called "Draft" but there`s an error. My code looks like that:

```
Sub copy_2()
  Sheets("Dividends").Range("A").Copy
  Sheets("Draft").Activate
  Range("A1").Select
  ActiveSheet.Paste
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: **Sheets("Dividends").Range("A:A").Copy**

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub copy_2()
  Sheets("Dividends").Range("A:A").Copy
  Sheets("Draft").Paste
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Removing references to `Active` as much as possible helps eliminate confusion.

Comment: @user7004 or just `Sheets("Dividends").Range("A:A").Copy Sheets("Draft").Range("A1")` on one line? Have you definitely got the spelling of the sheets correct?

Comment: yes, the spreadsheet names are correct. The error says "out of range", i tried this code Sub Macro1()
Sheets("Dividends").Range("A:A").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Draft").Range("A1").Paste
End Sub

Comment: Assuming the "sub out of range" error was in relation to the code I posted, which line is that error occurring on? When it throws the error, click 'Debug' and it will highlight the line it's trying to execute.

Comment: it highlights the sub line, so the first one

Comment: Is that the same place you were getting the error on your original code? Where is this code, is it on `Sheet1`, is it in `ThisWorkbook`, is it in some other module that you've added?

Comment: Something very odd going on. I just pasted that into a fresh workbook and got no such error. Maybe try deleting the whole `Sub` and retyping/copy-pasta it again? Maybe try a fresh workbook?

Comment: That's odd - I just ran the macro, and it worked for me (no errors).  Worked in a module, "thisworkbook" and "Dividends" page in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to copy/paste either - you can just set the ranges equal.

```
Sub copy()
Dim lastRow As Integer
'This will let us know the last used row in column A
lastRow = Sheets("Dividends").Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).row
Sheets("Draft").Range(Sheets("Draft").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("Draft").Cells(lastRow, 1)).Value = Sheets("Dividends").Range(Sheets("Dividends").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("Dividends").Cells(lastRow, 1)).Value
End Sub
```

Or you can copy/paste:

```
Sub copy()
Dim lastRow As Integer
'This will let us know the last used row in column A
lastRow = Sheets("Dividends").Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).row
Sheets("Dividends").Range(Sheets("Dividends").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("Dividends").Cells(lastRow, 1)).copy _
    Destination:=Sheets("Draft").Range(Sheets("Draft").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("Draft").Cells(lastRow, 1))

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

Note: If you have a gap anywhere in Column A, the lastRow integer might be off.  If you want to copy all the way down to the last used row, replace the "lastRow = " with this:

```
lastRow = Sheets("Dividends").UsedRange.Rows.Count
```

Comment: `Application.CutCopyMode = False
` is this necessary?

Comment: @Davesexcel - I'm not sure if you really need it for using Copy with Destination - but I've always read that when using copy it's not a bad idea.  Are there any downsides in including it?

Answer (score 0):

This works,

```
 Sheets("Dividends").Range("A:A").Copy Sheets("Draft").Range("A1")
```